# Avoid duplicate entries on Mongoose array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a many to many relation using mongoose, that looks like this.

```
TeamSchema = new Schema 
    name : String
    players: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'Player' }]
```

What I want to do is ensure that one Player doesnt appear two times in a Team.

When I do:

```
team.players.push(player)
team.save()
```

If I already added the player before, I see the players id two times on the team doc. Is there some kind of mongo/mongoose flag I can set so that the save method throws an exception, or doesn't add the player. I know I could do the check by hand, but I would prefer a simpler solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use the [`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/addToSet/) update operator like so:

```
Team.update({_id: team._id}, {$addToSet: {players: player}})
```

Assuming `player` is the ObjectId of a player, it will only be added to the team's `players` array if it's not already present.

Answer (score 12):

Just use [`addToSet`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_array_MongooseArray.addToSet) method:

```
team.players.addToSet(player)
team.save()
```